# Need to convert data set to string in C#

Tags: c#, string, dataset

Have an Excel data source which I am querying ok and posting data in data grid. The trick is that I want the data in a string variable but am failing to do that. I have tried arrayLists and arrays and I am not getting there yet because dataset has multiple data types (numbers, strings).

Please help me. Source code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>

<script language="C#" runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(Object Src, EventArgs E)
{
string strConn;

    string str="08/PST";
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
"Data Source=|DataDirectory|marks.xls;" +
"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
//You must use the $ after the object you reference in the spreadsheet
OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [Subject ID] FROM [Employees$] where emp_id='" + str + "'", strConn);
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
myCommand.Fill(myDataSet, "ExcelInfo");
DataGrid1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["ExcelInfo"].DefaultView;
DataGrid1.DataBind();
}
</script>
<html>
<head><title>Data Exported</title></head>
<body style="FONT-FAMILY: arial">
    <h2>Simple Data Report 
    </h2>
    <hr size="1" />
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:datagrid id="DataGrid1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="White" CellPadding="3" GridLines="None" CellSpacing="1">
            <HeaderStyle font-bold="True" forecolor="white" backcolor="#4A3C8C"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle backcolor="#DEDFDE"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:datagrid>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean that you want all data in a string variable?  You want to also import the excel datasource into a raw string? I just need clarification because I cannot visualize what you are asking.

Comment: Provide some more details please. "trick is that I want the data in a string variable" - not clear enough. What data do you want? You are binding dataset table and it`s ok. What string and from where do you want?

Comment: Object linking and emBLAAARGH!

Comment: A `DataSet` object is a (potentially) three-dimensional structure: `N` tables, each with `X` columns and `Y` rows.  A string is a *one-dimensional* structure: `N` characters.  Any mechanism for converting from `DataSet` to string will involve flattening out some part of that structure.

Answer (score 4):

Call the DataSet's GetXml() method.

Answer (score 2):

Right now your dataset is only getting the [Subject Id] in your dataset. So would you consider changing the query itself to return a string?

SQL SERVER:

```
SELECT CONVERT (VarChar, [Subject ID]) FROM [Employees$] where emp_id=
```

JET

```
SELECT CSTR ([Subject ID]) as [Subject ID] FROM [Employees$] where emp_id=
```

Answer (score 0):

Built a string as i read each row and was able to output it successfully

while (reader.Read())

```
            {
               string str="";

                str = str + reader[4].ToString().PadLeft(10) + '|' +
```

reader[5].ToString().PadLeft(1) + '|' + reader[6].ToString() + '\n';

```
            }
```